# How do you update the parameter of an Ecto Repo struct?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Not sure if my terminology is correct, so please correct.

It seems like it used to be as simple as passing in a struct with the updated parameters, which is still how all the examples I've found have been documented, like `Repo.update!(%{room | body: "A Room"})`

But now some key/primary key parameter seems to be required as well as a changeset, and I just can't seem to massage it into the format it wants, trying things like `Repo.update!(changeset, {id: 1})` and getting errors like:

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Ecto.Repo.Schema.update/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:216: Ecto.Repo.Schema.update(PingalServer.Repo, Ecto.Adapters.Postgres, #Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{body: "A Room", name: "first"}, errors: [], data: #PingalServer.Room<>, valid?: true>, {:id, 1})
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:135: Ecto.Repo.Schema.update!/4
```

Where the changeset is something like:

```
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil,
 changes: %{body: "A Room", name: "first"}, errors: [],
 data: #PingalServer.Room<>, valid?: true>
```

I'll have to do some more readings on changesets, but it seems like there should be some examples out there of what an update looks like under the new structure?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code used to create that changeset?

Comment: @Dogbert `changeset = Room.changeset(%Room{}, %{name: "first", body: "A Room"})`

Comment: This is a brand new record; it's not in the database. Why are you using `Repo.update`? `Repo.update` is to update records that already exist in the database.

Comment: @Dogbert I had mistaken that `%Room{}` was identifying the model and the key was identifying the specific struct. Thanks! Replacing `%Room{}` with the struct to update removes the need for the second parameter on `update()` altogether.

Answer (score 4):

The first param passed to `Ecto.repo.update!/2` **must** be a changeset (i.e. an `Ecto.Changeset` struct). see [ecto documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:update!/2), and pay attention to the type definition of the params and return value.

`%{room | body: "A Room"}` only gives you a map, not a changeset.

You can however *cast* some params onto the schema you fetched from the database to build a changeset.

```
room
|> Ecto.Changeset.cast(%{body: "A Room"}, [:body])
|> Repo.update!()
```

Or if you have defined `Room.changeset/2` (e.g. generated the model using `mix phoenix.gen.model`), you can also use it to get a changeset

```
room
|> Room.changeset(%{body: "A Room"})
|> Repo.update!()
```